# How to bind StackPanel to a non ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="stackPanel">
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding C}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding prop1}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

I am binding this stack panel to a list with this code

```
 List<C> list = new List<C>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
     list.Add(new C() { prop1 = "prop" });
 }
 stackPanel.DataContext = list;
```

And nothing happens. Do we have to always use `ObservableCollection`s? Or what else might be wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `{Binding C}` doesn't make sense, because you are putting the list itself into the DataContext. Then there is of course no property `C`.

You should replace it by this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

---

That said, you aren't actually binding a StackPanel to an items collection, but the ItemsControl inside the StackPanel. If you intended to use the StackPanel as the `ItemsPanel` of the ItemsControl, you should write it like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding prop1}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

and set the ItemsSource like this:

```
itemsControl.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: Thank you for the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `C` in `ItemsControl`'s `ItemsSource` like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Comment: Since this is also the correct answer and clear, I am upvoting it. thank you.